# birt report powerpoint text blocks for each sentence

Tags: powerpoint, birt

I'm creating reports with the birt engine, which are exported as pptx files. We have quite some text in it, and birt creates for each sentence (sometimes only for parts of a sentence) new text blocks inside pptx which our customer doesn't like because he wants to change parts of the text.

Is there a way to prevent it? I tried a dynamic text control instead of the data control but there was the same problem.

Regards

Comment: The answer you are looking for may be in this related question [What are BIRT and Excel doing with <email@madeup.com>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628715/what-are-birt-and-excel-doing-with-emailmadeup-com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older Versions of BIRT PPTX Emitter were built in a "PDF like" style. Drawbacks were:

- undesigned splitting of a single text blocks
- cell borders are painted not as real borders. Instead, a border is just a collection of single lines. Such a "border" doesn't match your table / grid cell as soon as you start modifying cell texts in the PowerPoint

There were no way to change behavior of the PPTX Emitter.

As far as I know, the PPTX Emitter was redesigned in version 4.5.0. There are a lot of pull requests like https://github.com/eclipse/birt/pull/122 to that theme. Try BIRT 4.5.0.

Comment: Thanks, that version helped fixing this. Only problem is that it isn't available in maven yet.